# How to open the .Result file generated by Spyder Profiler?

Tags: python, profiling, spyder

I used **Spyder's inbuilt profiler** to generate the following profiling results:

[image]

...I then pressed the **Save Button** to save the profiling results, which were saved a file with the extension `.Result`

**Question:** How do I open the `.Result` file to see my profiling results again? I tried to open it in Spyder and notepadd++, but it did not work.

**Version Info:**

[image]